# Calculating double integral with changing variables

Tags: calculus, integration

let $g(t)$ be a continues function that satisfy $\int_{-1}^{1}g(t)dt = 3$

let $f(x,y) = g(3x-y)$ calculate the double integral of $f(x,y)$ over the area $D=\{(x,y) : |3x|+|y|\le 1\}$

I tried to change variables and used $ |u|=|3x-y| \le1$ and $v=y$ between -1 and 1
. the jacubian is $\frac{1}{3}$ now I get that the integral is equal to 2 but it's wrong but when I use another substitution $u=3x-y$ and $v=3x+y$ I get the correct answer (1)

why does the first substitution isn't working

Comment: You need \ before braces in $\rm\LaTeX$ to make them render. Braces are part of $\rm\LaTeX$ macros, so they need to be handled in a special manner.

Answer (score 2):

If you do the substitution $X=3x+y$ and $Y=3x-y$, then\begin{align}\iint_Df(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy&=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\frac16f\left(\frac{X+Y}6,\frac{X-Y}2\right)\,\mathrm dX\,\mathrm dY\\&=\frac16\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1g\left(3\frac{X+Y}6-\frac{X-Y}2\right)\,\mathrm dX\,\mathrm dY\\&=\frac16\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1g(Y)\,\mathrm dX\,\mathrm dY\\&=\frac13\int_{-1}^1g(Y)\,\mathrm dY\\&=1.\end{align}

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the original post, I edited it, also why my sub isn't working?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Concerning your approach, I don't understand it. How is $|u|=|3x-y|$ a substitution?

Comment: u=3x-y, the absolute value is only for the bounds

Comment: If $u=3x-y$ and $v=y$, then what's the new region over which you are integrating?

Comment: both between -1 and 1

Comment: If both $3x-y$ and $y$ are equal to $1$, then $x=\frac23$. But $\left(\frac23,1\right)$ does not belong to the given region.